# Oracle error with Select into in memebr function in object type

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I'm having trouble with setting a member function inside of a type. I'm new to PL/SQL and having been trying to solve this for days without success.
I am aiming to have a method in singleDeck_type that will count the number of different body model types.

After much playing I have worked out that the only issue seems to be with my select statement, but the only error I receive is "Warning: execution completed with warning".

```
create or replace type bodyModel_Type as object(
modelID int,
modelName varchar2(45),
floorType varchar2(5),
manufacturer varchar2(45),
bLength number(8,2),
bWidth number(8,2),
noOfAxles int);
/
create table bodyModel_table of bodyModel_Type;
alter table bodyModel_table
Add (constraint bodyModel_PK primary key (modelID));

create or replace type engineModel_type as object(
engineModelID int,
engineDescription varchar2(45),

engineType varchar2(25),
engineCapacity int);
/
create table engineModel_table of engineModel_type;
alter table engineModel_table
Add (constraint engineModel_PK primary key (engineModelID));

create or replace type accessory_type as object(
accessoryID int,
accessoryName varchar2(45),
accessoryDescription varchar2(45),
installDate date);
/

create or replace type table_accessory_type as table of accessory_type;
/

create or replace type bus_type as object(
busID int,
registrationNo varchar2(10),
registrationExpireDate date,
bodyModel REF bodyModel_type,
engineModel Ref EngineModel_type)
not Final;
/
create table bus_table of bus_type;
alter table bus_table
Add (constraint bus_pk primary key (busID));



create or replace type singleDeck_type under bus_type(
noOfDoors int,
seatingCapacity int,
standingCapacity int);
/
create or replace type doubleDeck_type under bus_type(
lowerDeckSeatingCap int,
LowerDeckStandingCap int,
luggageCapacity number(8,2),
upperDeckCapacity int);
/
create table singleDeck_Table of singleDeck_Type;
alter table singleDeck_Table
Add (constraint SD_bus_pk primary key (busID));

create table doubleDeck_Table of doubleDeck_Type;
alter table doubleDeck_Table
Add (constraint DD_bus_pk primary key (busID));

ALTER TYPE singleDeck_type ADD MEMBER procedure count_bodytype
  RETURN NUMBER CASCADE;
  /
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY singleDeck_type
AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION count_bodytype
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  N REAL;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(S.busID)
  INTO N
  FROM singleDeck_Table s
  WHERE DEREF(s.bodyRef)=self;
  RETURN N;
END count_bodytype;

END;
/
```

Please, please HELP!!

Comment: `SHOW ERROR` would list you the errors.

Comment: When I enter SHOW ERROR, it says "No Errors."

Comment: That is because, `SHOW ERROR` would only display the error list of last compiled DDL. So, when you run a big list, you have to identify the once which caused error. And try run it seprately.

Comment: Or query the `user_errors` view, which will show the errors for all invalid PL/SQL objects.

Answer (score 0):

As OracleUser said, you can add `show errors` after each PL/SQL section in your script to show any errors generated; or at any time you can query the `user_errors` view to see the errors against all of your PL/SQL objects.

You're adding a member procedure but specifying a return type in the object specification. If it's returning something then it has to be a function, and you've done that correctly in the body.

```
ALTER TYPE singleDeck_type ADD MEMBER function count_bodytype
  RETURN NUMBER CASCADE;
/
```

The body does still have an error though:

```
ORA-00904: "S"."BODYREF": invalid identifier
```

You have a `bodyModel` field which is a `REF`, so I can only think you want to do:

```
  WHERE DEREF(s.bodyModel)=DEREF(self.bodyModel);
```

or

```
  WHERE DEREF(s.bodyModel).modelID=DEREF(self.bodyModel).modelID;
```

Although your query seems to be counting the number of single-deck buses with the same body model as the current one, which doesn't match what you said in the question, "count the number of different body model types". That sounds like something you'd need a [static method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjbas.htm#i467634) for, not a member method.

Comment: The member procedure instead of member function was just a rookie error.  When trying out everything I could think of to fix it I tried changing the function to a procedure and forgot to change it back prior to posting.  The compare table modelID to object modelID fixed my issue.  After all of that though I still couldn't get the Show error or User Error to display anything, but found that I could view the errors through the interface I was using in a different area. Thank you to all for your help. You are correct, I am trying to count the number of single-deck buses with the same body model.